# Finding $a$ and $b$ so that the function is continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}&\quad x<2\\[0.4em]
ax^2-bx+3&\quad 2 \leq x <3\\[0.3em]
2x-a+b&\quad x \geq 3
\end{cases}$$

I can't make the right limit of second piece equal to left limit of the first piece. And then how to solve for a and b? I get $4a-2b = 1$ but what do I do with that?

When I try to graph it I'm confused about how to get the $y$-values.

Comment: Look at $x = 2$ and $x = 3$. This will give you two equations in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: **Hint:** $x^2-4 = (x-2)(x+2)$

Comment: I for lim (x to 2+) I get 4a-2b+3 and for lim(x to 3-) i get 6-a+b

Answer (score 2):

First note that $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb R \backslash \{2, 3\}$. Then take the limits as $x$ approaches those two points:
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 2^-}f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 2^-}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = 4\\
\lim_{x \to 2^+}f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 2^+}\left[ax^2 - bx + 3\right] = 4a - 2b + 3 = f(2)\\
\lim_{x \to 3^-}f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 3^-}\left[ax^2 - bx + 3\right] = 9a - 3b + 3\\
\lim_{x \to 3^+}f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 3^+}\left[2x - a + b\right] = 6 - a + b = f(3)\\
\end{align}$$

The first two have to be equal, and that holds for the last two as well. That's because if $x_0$ is an accumulation point for $f$, then $f$ is continuous in $x_0$ if $\lim_\limits{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_2)$: for this to happen the limits from the sides have to be equal. We then have a system of two equations in two unknowns, which is solvable:
$$\begin{cases}
4a - 2b + 3 &= 4\\
9a - 3b + 3 &= 6 - a + b
\end{cases}$$

The solution to the system is
$$\begin{cases}
a = \frac12\\
b = \frac12
\end{cases}$$

And those two values are the only values for which $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I forget how to solve for two variables in the same equation...did you guess and check?

Comment: if 'a' and 'b' are equal, then the only continuity in the function is a single point?

Comment: a and b just happen to be equal.

Comment: @teri $a$ and $b$ are just variables. It doesn't mean anything whether or not they are equal. If you mean discontinuity, there are none.

Comment: @teri: There is no relation between $a$ and $b$. What matters is if the system has a solution or not. In this case it has the solution $(\frac12, \frac12)$. That means there is one value of $a$ together with one value of $b$ that make the function continuous over $\mathbb R$.

To solve a system of equation you don't guess and check, that would take too much time (possibly infinite). There are much better methods. Search how to solve a system of two equations in two unknowns.

Finally, if I helped you, would you accept the answer? Thanks!